# Finding the maximum row of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have written a recursive function that I believe will return the 'maximum' row of the 4x4 matrix it is fed. By 'maximum' I mean that the maximum row of the matrix.

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

is row 4 (on account of the first column's values); the maximum row of the matrix

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
4 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

is row 3 (on account of the first and second columns' values); the maximum row of the matrix

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
4 4 1 2
4 4 2 3
```

is row 4 (on account of the first, second, and third columns' values); the maximum row of the matrix

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
4 4 1 2
4 4 1 3
```

is row 4 (on account of the values in every column); and the maximum row of the matrix

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
4 4 1 3
4 4 1 3
```

is row 3 (on account of the values in every column - pick the topmost row).

This function is a lot more involved than I expected when I sat down to write it. Please tell me there's an easier way to express this algorithm in C!

(The function is employed in a program written by a Pascalite; please forgive the fact that the arrays ignore their 0th member!)

Here's the function (together with its helper `indexOf()`, which is never fed an array in which val fails to appear!) Apologies for variable indentation - bit of a nightmare just getting it to this state!

```
int indexOf(int a[], int val) 
{ /* returns index at which val occurs in a[] */
    int i=1;

    while(a[i] != val)
        i++;

    return i;
}

int maxRow (int a[5][5], int index) 
{
  int store [5] = {-1, a[1][index], a[2][index], a[3][index], a[4][index] };
  int store2[5] = {-1, a[1][index], a[2][index], a[3][index], a[4][index] };

  int i, j, k, max, i1=0, i2=0, i3=0, i4=0;
  int arr[5]={-1,-1,store2[2],store2[3],store2[4]};

  if (index==5)
  {
    if(a[1][4]>=0)
        return 1;
    else if(a[2][4]>=0)
        return 2;
    else if(a[3][4]>=0)
        return 3;
    else if(a[4][4]>=0)
        return 4;               
  }

  /* order store[] from max -> min: */ 

  for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
  {  
    max=store[i]; 
    j=i;
    for(k=i+1; k<=4; k++)
        if(store[k]>max)
        {
            max=store[k];
            j=k;
        }
    store[j]=store[i]; 
    store[i]=max;
  } 

  i1 = indexOf(store2, store[1]);

  /* now we must indicate which (if any ) rows to recurse on... */

  if (store[1]==store[2])
  {         
    if(i1==1)           
        i2 = indexOf(arr,store[1]);     
    else if (i1==2)
    {
        arr[2] = -1;
        i2 = indexOf(arr, store[1]);        
    }
    else if (i1==3)
        i2 = 4;

    /* note: if i2==4 then can't have store[1] equal to any other members of store[] */

    if(store[1]==store[3])
    {
        /* i2 = 2 or 3 */

        if(store2[4] <= store2[3])          
            i3 = 3;         
        else i3=4;      

        if (store[1]==store[4])
        {
            i4=4;
        }
    }  
  }      

    if (i2==0) 
        return i1;

    else if(i3==0)
    {
          i = indexOf(store2,store[4]);

          for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            a[i][j]=-1; 

          i = indexOf(store2,store[3]);

          for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            a[i][j]=-1;         

          return maxRow(a, index+1);              
    }   
    else if (i4==0)
    {
      i = indexOf(store2,store[4]);

      for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            a[i][j]=-1; 
      return maxRow(a, index+1);
    }
    else /* all i are non-zero */
      return maxRow(a, index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I'd do if I were refactoring this code is get rid of recursion.

You should be able to do it with a variable to keep track of "best row number so far", and a simple "for each row" loop. Inside the loop would be code that compares the current row with the best row so far (and does "best row so far = current row" if the current row is better).

Example:

```
int maxRow(int a[4][4]) {
    int i,j;
    int bestRow = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] !=  a[bestRow][j]) {
                if(a[i][j] > a[bestRow][j]) {
                    bestRow = i;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bestRow;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to simply compare two rows at a time and find which rows are the greatest seen so far:

iterative version:

```
int maxrow(int *matrix, int width, int height) {       
    int maxrowindex = 0; // first, assume the first row is the maxrow
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < height; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            if (matrix[maxrowindex*width+c] != matrix[r*width+c]) {
                if (matrix[maxrowindex*width+c] < matrix[r*width+c]) {
                    maxrowindex = r;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxrowindex;
}
```

recursive version:

```
int lexicographic_compare(int a[], int b[], int width) {
    if (width == 1) return a[0] <= b[0];
    if (a[0] == b[0]) return lexicographic_compare(a+1, b+1, width-1);
    return a[0] <= b[0];
}   
int maxrow(int *matrix, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 1) return 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = maxrow(matrix + width, width, height-1) + 1;
    if (lexicographic_compare(matrix+a*width, matrix+b*width, width)) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return a;
    }   
}
```

this code should work for a matrix of arbitrary size.

Comment: For the iterative `maxrow()`, you might as start with `for (r = 1; r < height; r++)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use strcmp(char*, char*) to compare two strings. If you convert the matrix rows to the equivalent characters, then the strcmp() will do the hard work for you.

```
int isFirstGreater = strcmp("1234", "1232");
```

This will return 1 to say that the first string is greater. In your context:

```
for(int i=0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
{
    charArray[i] = (char*) matrixRow[i];
}
charArray[MatrixSize] = 0; // You need to add a zero to make it a string. 
strcmp(charArray, anotherCharArray);
```

However, this does seem like a bit of a crude hack.

Maybe this is better:

```
int number = 0;
for(int i=0; i< matrixSize; i++)
{
    number += matrixRow[i] * pow(10, (matrixSize-i)-1);
}
```

That just converts the matrix row to a number, which you can just use >, < to see which is bigger, which is the equivalent to your original goal.

Comment: this won't work if the matrix contains a number greater than 9.

Comment: As it happens, 9 is the maximum number that this matrix will contain!

Comment: It should work fine. I'll give a better example.

Comment: That's OK Mowgli - I think I can take it from here...

Comment: It will work for numbers up to 255 (as a char is only a byte). I suggest you use the second method- convert to a number.

Comment: instead can use 
' number = number*<MAX_MATRIX_VALUE + 1> + matrixRow[i] '
This pattern is fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive solution could look like this (sorry, no C code, but an algorithm description instead):

- Keep a `bool` array *`row_ruled_out[4]`* with one item per row. This array will be used to keep track of which rows have already been "ruled out". Initially, all rows are still considered "in".
- For each column of your matrix, do the following:

  1. Find the maximum number *m* appearing in the column. For example, in the following matrix column:

     ```
       . a . .
       . b . .
       . c . .
       . d . .
     ```

     *m* = max(*a*, *b*, *c*, *d*).
  2. For each row that hasn't yet been ruled out (according to *`row_ruled_out`*), if its value in that column is less than *m*, it cannot be the largest row. Therefore mark that row as "ruled out" in the *`row_ruled_out`* array. It won't be considered any further.
- After you've done the above for each column, look at *`row_ruled_out`*. All rows that are left, ie. haven't been ruled out, must be the largest rows. This could be zero, one, or several rows, depending on your input.

Comment: A small correction: at step 1, you should only consider the columns of the rows that hasn't been ruled out.

Comment: This was a mistake I too made in an earlier version of the function...

Answer (score 0):

with tests....  just comparing every row....

```
#include "seatest.h"


int m1[4][4] = { 
    {1,2,3,4},
    {2,3,4,1},
    {3,4,1,2},
    {4,1,2,3}};


int m2[4][4] = { 
    {1,2,3,4},
    {2,3,4,1},
    {4,4,1,2},
    {4,1,2,3}};

int m3[4][4] = { 
    {1,2,3,4},
    {2,3,4,1},
    {4,4,1,2},
    {4,4,2,3}};

int m4[4][4] = { 
    {1,2,3,4},
    {2,3,4,1},
    {4,4,1,2},
    {4,1,1,3}};

int m5[4][4] = { 
    {1,2,3,4},
    {2,3,4,1},
    {4,4,1,3},
    {4,1,1,3}};


int compare(int* d1, int* d2, int l)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++) 
    {
        if(d1[i] > d2[i]) return 1;
        if(d1[i] < d2[i]) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int matrix_max_row_r(int* m, int w, int h)
{
    int i;  
    int max = 0;
    for(i=1; i<h; i++) max = compare(m+(w*i), m+(w*(i-1)), w) > 0 ? i : max;
    return max;
}



int matrix_max_row(int* m)
{
    return matrix_max_row_r(m, 4,4);
}


void test_max_matrix_row()
{   
    assert_int_equal(3, matrix_max_row((int*)m1));
    assert_int_equal(2, matrix_max_row((int*)m2));
    assert_int_equal(3, matrix_max_row((int*)m3));
    assert_int_equal(2, matrix_max_row((int*)m4));
    assert_int_equal(2, matrix_max_row((int*)m5));
}

void test_fixture_matrix( void )
{
    test_fixture_start();      
    run_test(test_max_matrix_row);   
    test_fixture_end();       
}

void all_tests( void )
{
    test_fixture_matrix();   
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    run_tests(all_tests);   
    return 0;
}
```